# ngb-accordion implement cdkdrag in ngb-panel

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm try to create accordion using `ngb-accordion` with drag and drop support using `cdkdrag`,

but when I'm using
`<ngb-panel *ngFor="let content of children; let i = index" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="content">`

my drag and drop nothing happen, then I try move cdkdrag in

```html
<ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
   <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"  cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="content">
```

this creates drag and drop functionality but, when dragging some card-title and try hover to other ngbPanelHeader, the view not sorting well and the destination is gone. I think it the structure of ngb-panel create `div class="card"` and I try to drag element inside `div class="card-title`

are there any people already successful created ngb-accordion with drag and drop support?

Answer (score 0):

I'm decided to using material accordion, that many sample material with cdkdrag